# MySQL Left Join returns error

Tags: mysql, left-join

Maybe I just haven't done a LEFT JOIN in too long, but I'm perplexed.

Here are my tables:

```
Table: user_phones

user    phone       carrier
----------------------------
danny   5045551234  Verizon
mom     5551234567  T-Mob
tony    5121234567  T-Mob

Table carriers

carrier    email_exchange
--------------------------
Verizon    vtext.com
T-Mob      tmomail.net
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT user, CONCAT(phone, '@', email_exchange) AS sms
LEFT JOIN carriers ON (user_phones.carrier = carriers.carrier)
FROM user_phones
```

And I keep getting back:

> 'LEFT JOIN carriers ON (user_phones.carrier = carriers.carrier) FROM
>   user_phones'

I know this is a bonehead oversight, but variations are not helping (putting the `ON` clause in parenthesis, etc) is not working.

Where am I slipping up?

Comment: I think you need *FROM* before *LEFT JOIN*

Comment: As noted below, my mind blew a gasket and I was confusing `FROM` and `WHERE`.  Told you it was a bonehead oversight.

Comment: "Error occurred between keyboard and chair."  We've all been there.

Comment: Layer 8 Error, the worst.  I needed the refresher for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `FROM user_phones`

```
SELECT a.`user`, 
       CONCAT(a.`phone`, '@', b.`email_exchange`) AS sms
FROM user_phones a LEFT JOIN carriers b 
        ON a.carrier = b.carrier
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `FROM` clause before your `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT `user`, CONCAT(phone, '@', email_exchange) AS sms
FROM user_phones LEFT JOIN carriers ON user_phones.carrier = carriers.carrier
```

A minor suggestion would be to use an auto increment `id` field in your `carriers` table, update `user_phones.carrier` to hold those `id`s, and join on that. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT user, CONCAT(phone, '@', email_exchange) AS sms
FROM user_phones
LEFT JOIN carriers ON (user_phones.carrier = carriers.carrier)
```

[w3schools - Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Is this always the case? Putting the left join after the from? Why I do I feel like I've done it the other way around?

Comment: Yeah, you need to specify what I guess you could call the "base" table, or the starting point.

Comment: Okay, it really has been awhile since I've done this simple a query. I was getting my `FROM` mixed up with my `WHERE`. Let the laughter begin.